# KVM: Reboots virtual machine reboots the virtualizer machine too

Tags: linux, boot, kvm, reboot, crash

Rebooting or booting the virtual machine triggers an immediate reboot of the virtializer machine.
No matter if I'm on SSH or I do it by VIRSH command or I press the PLAY button in VMM.

I am using KVM on Oracle Linux 9.1. The virtualized operating system is Oracle Linux 9.1 too.

Does anyone know what's going on?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you sure you aren't doing it the other way around?

Comment: I'm sure. Rebooting on the VM shell will reboot metal.

Comment: what if you try a different virtual distro, for the sake of testing

Comment: any live-cd or something to boot causes this

Comment: so the issue is with the "host" system - that kinda sucks - I got nothing, sorry

Comment: there is a probability like 1/2 that the virtual machine will start normally